# Navigate backward and forward through my code (visited history)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need 2 buttons for backward and forward navigation throughout my code (visited history), like I do in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Windows, use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> to go back / forward in your code.

Linux, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to go back and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to go forward.

Mac OS, use <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to go back and <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to go forward.

Here are the keyboard shortcut references.

- https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf
- https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf
- https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

Comment: Aha. You want buttons in the graphic user interface.